# Microservices use an independent database or share a database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-cloud

Recently, I encountered a problem when I opened the software. Whether the microservice architecture should use a shared database or a separate database for each service. Because I have been using the single architecture development model before this, the microservice architecture is not yet familiar, so the problem of the microservice architecture database cannot be understood. According to the concept of microservices, each service runs in an independent process and communicates through a lightweight communication method. That is to say, the storage of each service does not interfere with each other. How to manage the data between services ?

Looking forward to the answer of the gods.

Comment: What is the reason behind changing from single architecture development model (I assume it is a monolith now) to micro services architecture? What were the challenges you faced in monolith that made you decide to go with micro services style? Does the application you have now, is it a big complex domain that should support millions of users? And I couldn't understand what do you mean by "when I opened the software"

Answer (score 1):

The issue of which data residency architecture you "should" use depends on your business requirements. There is no single answer to this.

At my last job, we had to think about security audits as well as technical architecture choices. If an auditor comes in and says, "can you show me the code that accesses this database, so I can verify data access supports security and privacy policies?" and we say, "well, uh, lots of applications share access to this data, so it's complex to answer that question." Then that's going to make the auditor's job harder, and we're going to be spending *months* proving that we're in compliance with those policies.

That's why it may be an advantage to stick with the strict architecture that each microservice "owns" its own database, and only that microservice can access that database. Then the auditor can inspect the code for any single microservice in a pretty reasonable amount of time.

How to manage data between microservices is simple: expose data through APIs. Each microservice can *request* specific data from another microservice, but then you can write very business-specific role-based access control code, and this is easier to implement the code and easier to test and audit than the typical database privileges.

(Tangent: In NoSQL databases, it's even more important to implement RBAC in the application, because many NoSQL databases don't have features for access control.)

If you use the architecture of separate database instances per microservice, and never can you cross the streams, does this add to the cost and complexity of your infrastructure? Yes, of course.

But on the other hand, in addition to enforcing access control and privacy, it makes it easy to do other operational things like:

- Track resource usage and costs per microservice
- Optimize server configuration for the traffic patterns of each microservice
- Backup and archive data appropriately to the needs of each microservice
- Retire obsolete microservices and their resources

Sorry to go into the weeds a little bit, but it is worthwhile to think about architecture choices with respect to operation as well as development.